# sequelize query that implements calculation using provided value and table row value

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

equivalent sequelize query for the following raw query:

```
SELECT
  *,
  (distance1 - table.distance) as distance
FROM
  table
HAVING
  distance >= 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Translation.findAll({
    attributes: { include: [[models.sequelize.fn('LENGTH', models.sequelize.col('value')), 'total']] },
    having: {total: {lte: 10}}
}).then(function(result) {
    result.forEach(function(t) {
        ...
    });
})
```

is equivalent to

```
SELECT *, LENGTH(`value`) AS `total` 
FROM `content_translation` 
HAVING `total` <= 10;
```

And works.

I think you should have somthing like

```
table.findAll({
    attributes: { include: [['(distance1 - distance)', 'distance']] },
    having: {distance: {gte: 10}}
}).then(function(result) {
    result.forEach(function(t) {
        ...
    });
})
```

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#findalloptions-promisearrayinstance